# Next js клиентские запросы

Tags: nextjs

Хочу зделать запрос на сервер с клиента но проблема в том что, если я перезагружаю страницу в консоли я получаю пустой массив и undefined, если я поменяю чтото в коде(чтоб началась компиляция) то тогда на клиент приходяд данные, можно ли это исправить?

```
const router = useRouter()
const { id } = router.query
const URL = `http://localhost:4500/theme/${id}`

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        if (id) {
            setLoad(true)
            const response = await fetch(URL)
            const data = await response.json()
            setData(data)
            setLoad(false)
        }
    }
    fetchData()
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const {data, setData} = useState('');
useEffect(() => {
    async func(){
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const data = await res.json();
        setData(data)
    }

   func();
}, [])




return ({data === '' ? <div>loading...</div> : <div>data</div>});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]